# JavaScript - Copy to clipboard does not work on Windows machines

Tags: javascript, copy

I have this function, works perfectly in unix based OS (Linux, MacOS), but somehow, does not works in Windows, it just simply does not add anything to the clipboard.

This is running in a NextJS App.

```
export const copyRichContent = async rich => {

    const html = new Blob([rich], { type: 'text/html' })
    const data = new ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': html })
    await navigator.clipboard
         .write([data])
         .then(e => console.log('All good', e))
         .catch(err => {
           console.error(err)
         })

}
```

- I already tried with clipboard-pollyfill
- I tried in Windows with Firefox and Chrome
- If I use the MIME type "text/plain", it works (but I need to use html)
- The app is running securely (with HTTPS)
- I confirmed I have the write text and write text delayed permissions
- No errors in the catch block

I expect to be working in Windows machines, no matter the browser.

Comment: And adding a `catch` to write does not give any errors?

Comment: hey somethinghere, unfortunately there are no errors in the catch block, I have updated my question though, thanks for taking the time to offer a suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not pasting the copied data into a RCE (What a moron, right?).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I) First, use https://permission.site/ to check if copy and past are working in your browser (at the bottom of the page you have the clipboard read/write tests). If it does not work... the problem is not in your code (you may open the console devtools to have more details).

II) Consider the security aspects. Your code must run in a SECURITY CONTEXT (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write). One of the main aspect is that your page must be HTTPS. But read the previous link, it is a good to know link.

III) On Windows, when you put text/html in the clipboard, you must provide a text/plain alternative.

Look at this example perfectly working on Windows :

```
let button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerText = 'Copy'
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const rich = '<p>Hello <b>world 1</b> and go to <a href="">Link</a>! at ' + Date.now() + '</p>'
    console.log('isSecureContext=', window.isSecureContext)
    const plain = new Blob([rich], { type: 'text/plain' })
    const html = new Blob([rich], { type: 'text/html' })
    const data = new ClipboardItem({ 'text/plain': plain, 'text/html': html })
    await navigator.clipboard.write([data])
})
document.body.append(button)
```

IV) Be careful with the RichTextEditor you are using for tests. Some are not working properly (Ex: it will not work if you past your HTML in WordPad). Use an online RichTextEditor to check.

Keep us posted

Comment: Thank you Michaël, I have followed all the suggestions you offered and unfortunately, the result is the same:

1- I have checked the permissions, I have both enabled (Write text and write text delayed).
2- Thank you for the security info, I have ensured my app is running securely, using HTTPS.
3- I have provided the text/plain alternative as well.

Current behavior: In Windows Machines (Using Chrome/Firefox), the HTML is not copied, now that I'm using the additional mime type text/plain, it does copy the plain text, but of course, with all the HTML tags (Not the desired output).

Comment: I'm more curious now to know why does not work properly in Windows, and in Linux and MacOS, the copied text is good and when pasting it into a Word, Google Docs document or in an email body, it retains the format (I'm using some h1, h2. h3. b HTML tags)

Comment: It's very intriguing!

1) Just to be sure, test the previous code in https://codepen.io/Micha-l-LEBRETON/pen/QWoOVBq, click COPY and paste the result in a Rich Editor like https://richtexteditor.com/demos/default.aspx . Is it working or not ?
2) Just to be sure, are you working with Virtual Machines ?
3) Give us more details please. I'm missing something specific to your situation.

Comment: Hey Michaël LEBRETON ! With those steps it worked, if I paste to a rich content editor it pastes the data properly, sorry for this, my bad, I didn't know this was the way the system clipboard works.

Comment: Super! It depends of the target software. It's why it's good to have HTML and plain text in the clipboard.

Comment: But it's strange that it does not work in Word !!!